# mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'user'@'%'

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I am using python to create a mysql.user granting him the access from all servers in the network, using this command:

```
    cursor.execute("CREATE USER '"+user+"'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '"+password+"';");
```

but facing this issue :

> mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'user'@'%'

while executing the above command, should I update it to fix the issue ?

Comment: Is the user you are using to connect with the database permitted to create new users and grant privileges?

Comment: I am connecting to the db as 'root ', so, I have the permission to do that

Comment: Can you create a user by directly connecting to MySQL? See example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fix-error-1396-hy000-operation-create-user-failed-in-mysql)

Comment: yes I can create a user like that: 'user'@'localhost' but not 'user'@'%' can access from any server

Comment: I am connecting to the db as root, I have all needed privileges to create that 'user'@'%' but seems missing something !

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are also unable to create the user even from the command line... Really looks like a grants issue to me; can you use `show grants;` to check your privileges?

Comment: I did this as a workaround: cursor.execute("CREATE USER '"+user+"'@'"+server+"' IDENTIFIED BY '"+password+"';")  and then cursor.execute("UPDATE IGNORE mysql.user SET host='%' WHERE Host='"+server+"' AND User='"+user+"';") and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

you can create a user like this:

```
cursor.execute("CREATE USER '"+user+"'@'"+server+"' IDENTIFIED BY '"+password+"';")
```

then give the user access from anywhere using this command:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE IGNORE mysql.user SET host='%' WHERE Host='"+server+"' AND User='"+user+"';")
```